# Eventually constant variable assignments

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

One proof of the Downward Löwenheim Skolem Theorem is via consideration of elementary substructures. In a discussion of this theorem, Christopher Leary writes the following:

"Suppose that $ \mathfrak{L}$ is a countable language and $ \mathfrak{B}$ is an $ \mathfrak{L}$-structure. Then $ \mathfrak{B}$ has a countable elementary substructure... assume $\textit{B}$ (the underlying set of $ \mathfrak{B}$)  is uncountable. As the language $ \mathfrak{L}$ is countable, there are only countably many $ \mathfrak{L}$-formulas, and thus only countably many formulas of the form $\exists x \alpha$.

Let $A_o$  be any nonempty countable subset of $\textit{B}$. We show how to build $A_1$  such that $A_o \subseteq A_1$ , and $A_1$ is countable. The idea is to add to $A_o$ witnesses for the truth (in the structure $ \mathfrak{B}$) of existential statements.

Notice that as $A_o$ is countable, there are only countably many functions $s'$: Vars → $A_o$ that are eventually constant. (This is a nice exercise for those of you who have had a course in set theory...) Also, if we are given any φ and any $s$ : Vars → $A_o$, we can find an eventually constant $s'$ : Vars → $A_o$ such that $s$ and $s'$ agree on the free variables of φ"

What does Leary mean by "eventually constant" in this context? Why is the variable assignment $s'$ eventually constant in this case? What might be a proof of the "nice exercise" that Leary refers to?

I would be extremely happy if you have answers to my questions.

Answer (score 1):

I think that a function "that is eventually constant" is a function $s : Vars \to A_0$ such that for some $n_0 : s(v_k)=s(v_h)$, for any $h,k > n_0$.

In words, from "some point on" the function has a "constant value".

Being the set $A_0$ countable, such functions with values in it must be at most countable.

The last step of the argument follows from the fact that any formula $\varphi$ is a string of finite lenght : thus, it can have only a finite number of *free* variables.

So, having $s$ and $\varphi$, we can find $n_0$ such that for all the variables $v_k$ occurring free in $\varphi$ : $k \le n_0$.

Having found it, we can choose an assignment $s'$ such that $s'$ agree with $s$ on the first $n_0$ variables (i.e. $s'(v_k)=s(v_k)$, for $k \le n_0$) and in addition $s'$ is constant from $n_0$ on.

---

Regarding the "nice exercise", see [Cardinal arithemtic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_number#Cardinal_arithmetic).