# Eventually constant assignment function of Downward Lowenheim-Skolem theorem

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, first-order-logic

I have just finished reading the proof of Downward Lowenheim-Skolem Theorem and have been reading the article [Eventually constant variable assignments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1271131/eventually-constant-variable-assignments) and the second edition of the book, “A Friendly Introduction to Mathematic Logic”

However, I still don’t know what’s the use of eventually constant variable assignment in the proof of Downward Lowenheim-Skolem Theorem
I understand the definition of  eventually constant variable assignment as being
$\forall i, j, \exists k \in \mathbb{N}, i, j > k, s’(v_{i}) = s’(v_{j})$

Why it must be eventually constant?

[Content of the book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8Epz.jpg)

[Content of the book(2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqTH8.jpg)

Comment: (1) You can [edit] your posts. (2) There's no use, it's all the same, since formulas are finite in length, any two assignments that agree on the values of the free variables of a formula will give the same truth value.

Comment: (1) Oh, thank you! (2) I understand, if two assignment agree on the values of free variables, it will return the same truth value if they assign the bound variable to same element in the universe